# Adding Super Key to Atom editor's key bindings

Tags: linux, coffeescript, key-bindings, atom-editor, cson

I've made the switch from kate to Github's Atom editor and I'm enjoying all the plugins and extras it has.  One thing that I can't figure out however is to make use of the linux "super key" in atom's key bindings (Also known as the Windows key).  Atom keeps its key bindings in `.cson` files and I haven't been able to find any reference to super.  Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Why did you tag the question with `coffeescript`?

Comment: @frhd fair question.  The reason I used the tag is because CSON (the notation containing key-binding customization here) is the object notation for coffeescript.  As CSON is a coffeescript derivative (and not especially widely used in its own right) I figured it would be worth asking the coffeescript community as well.  Sound reasonable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work with a windows keyboard, I'm using an apple keyboard, but `cmd` seems to work as the `Super` key for me.

In my keymap file, I enter code like this:

```
 'atom-workspace':
   'cmd-i': 'core:move-up'
   'cmd-k': 'core:move-down'
   'ctrl-d':'editor:delete-to-beginning-of-line'
```

Hope this helps.